# Unable to get SSMTP working on linux terminal

Tags: linux, email, gmail, ssmtp

I recently installed SSMTP on my Raspbian OS to send an alert to my email via a triggering event. However, I'm unable to send the simplest form of email. When I execute the command: `echo "This is a test" | mail -v -s "Test" myemailaddress@gmail.com` I receive this response:

```
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP xxxxxxxxxxxxx.56 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO raspberrypi
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[->] EHLO raspberrypi
[<-]
send-mail:  (raspberrypi)
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

My config file looks like this:

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=myemailaddress@gmail.com
AuthPass=mypassword
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

I've allowed less secure apps on my Gmail. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong since many other tutorial have shown that these configurations will work. Any help appreciated.